# how can I use github in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone?

Tags: github, windows-phone

Should 
I install github in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend integrating git into visual studio.

However, you can use [standalone Github application](https://windows.github.com/). I've been using it for a long time for my Windows Phone projects, it works OK.

P.S. And one more thing. You shouldn't use VS 2010: the SDK is too old, and is long unsupported. You can, and you should, migrate to visual studio 2012 or 2013 - it supports building apps for windows phone 7.5+